# How to find the $n_{th}$ derivative for the following?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$f(x) = \exp(Ax^{-2/\alpha}\rho(x,\alpha,r)) $$

where $$\rho(x,\alpha,r) = \int^\infty_{r^2x^{-2/\alpha}} \frac{1}{1+u} du$$

I have to find the $n_{th}$ derivate of $f(x)$, i.e.
$$(-1)^n \frac{d^n f(x)}{fx^n}$$

Notice, the tricky part is the $x$ in the limit of the $rho$ function.

All other elements in the equations are assumed constant except $x$

Comment: I'm not sure $\rho$ is well-defined. I mean, for fixed $r,x\in\mathbb R$, if $\alpha\neq 0$, the integral diverges, so $\rho(x)$ is not defined.

Comment: Is there no way to solve this?

Comment: The problem I think is that, if $r^2x^{-2/\alpha}$ is a positive number $y_0\in \mathbb R$, the integral $$\int_{y_0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1+u} du $$ diverges. Maybe you are forgetting an exponential in the denominator. Otherwise, I think the problem hasn't got solution.

Comment: nah....I am not forgetting any exponential. That I am sure. I have checked my solution to this part a few times but always reach to similar notations. I will re-check and see if somehow $x$ can be omitted.

Comment: Ok. Good luck. Anyway, maybe other users can help you more than me.

Comment: And if you fix $\rho$, which does diverge as written, you need a formula for the n-th derivative of $e^{f(x)}$. Writing this as $g_n(f)e^f$, we have $g_{n+1}=g_n'+g_nf'$ and this gets messy. See Faa de Bruno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\rho(x,\alpha,r)$ is defined only if $x\ge 0$ and is convergent if so. Then it would be$$\rho(x,\alpha,r)=\ln(1+r^2x^{-\dfrac{2}{\alpha}})$$by substituting in $f(x)$ we have$$f(x)=(1+r^2x^{-\dfrac{2}{\alpha}})e^{Ax^{-\dfrac{2}{\alpha}}}$$the nth differentiation can be calculated through Taylor's series but not explicitly. Therefore:$$f(x)=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A^{n-1}\dfrac{A+nr^2}{n!}x^{-\dfrac{2n}{\alpha}}$$The case where $-\dfrac{2}{\alpha}\in\Bbb N$ is simple and for the other cases we have$$(-1)^n\frac{d^n f(x)}{dx^n}=(-1)^n\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-\dfrac{2k}{\alpha})(-\dfrac{2k}{\alpha}-1)...(-\dfrac{2k}{\alpha}-n+1)A^{k-1}\dfrac{A+kr^2}{k!}x^{-\dfrac{2k}{\alpha}-n}$$and using the Gamma function we finally obtain$$(-1)^n\frac{d^n f(x)}{dx^n}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\Gamma(-\dfrac{2k}{\alpha}+1)}{\Gamma(-\dfrac{2k}{\alpha}-n+2)}A^{k-1}\dfrac{A+kr^2}{k!}x^{-\dfrac{2k}{\alpha}-n}$$

Comment: So should I just assume that the function $rho (x,\alpha,r)$ is convergent?
Would there be consequences on rest of my analytical solutions?